# Selecting different variables for each participant to calculate a unique score

Tags: r, for-loop, casting, lapply

I have a dataframe where I would like to check if people identified their right theme from a memory test. Each participant saw a different stimuli(s), so doing so is slightly more complicated than I expected. The first participant, for instant, saw the suicide, the memory, and the time themes, so if they have a 1 in those variable columns thats good. If they have a 1 in a column that they didn't see, thats bad. For instant, participant 1 below correctly identified all of their images, because they were shown suicide, memory, and time, and have a 1 in that column, and a 0 in the other columns. However the next participant said they saw the memory column but didnt. I would like to create four additional columns that show 1 if they got the theme correctly (saw the theme and marked 1 or didnt see the theme and marked 0), and 0 if they got it incorrect (saw the theme and marked it 0 or didn't see the theme and marked it 1).

I'm a little at a loss on how to do this and appreciate the help!!!

```
list <- c("suicide memory time","suicide vomit time","vomit alcohol time","  ",
"  ","alcohol suicide children")
id <- c(1:6)
suicide1<- c(1,1,0,0,0,1)
suicide2<- c(1,1,1,0,0,1)
memory1 <- c(1,0,0,1,0,0)
memory2 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0)
alcohol<- c(0,1,1,1,1,1)
time<-    c(1,0,1,1,1,0)
foil1<-   c(0,0,0,0,0,0)
foil2 <-  c(0,0,1,0,0,0)
df<- data.frame(list,id,suicide,memory,alcohol, time, foil1, foil2)
```

How do I create 8 new columns:
suicide1_score
memory2_score... etc  that show 0/1 for each participant based on what they actually saw?

Answer (score 1):

```r
nms <- names(df)[3:8]
out <- t(sapply(strsplit(df$list, " "), match, x = nms, nomatch = 0L))
colnames(out) <- paste0(nms, "_score")
cbind(df, data.frame(+(out > 0)))
#                       list id suicide memory alcohol time foil1 foil2 suicide_score memory_score alcohol_score time_score foil1_score foil2_score
# 1      suicide memory time  1       1      1       0    1     0     0             1            1             0          1           0           0
# 2       suicide vomit time  2       1      0       1    0     0     0             1            0             0          1           0           0
# 3       vomit alcohol time  3       0      0       1    1     0     1             0            0             1          1           0           0
# 4                           4       0      0       1    1     0     0             0            0             0          0           0           0
# 5                           5       0      0       1    1     0     0             0            0             0          0           0           0
# 6 alcohol suicide children  6       1      0       1    0     0     0             1            0             1          0           0           0
```

Comment: It's funny that you're splitting the string.... I created it for this problem but can see how that wasn't maybe the best. The original location of the themes are in 2 variables: 
```
sdt<- sdt %>%
  mutate(warning_theme_list = paste(warning_theme1, warning_theme2, warning_theme3, sep = " "))
``` 
maybe I should just input that into the first part of the sapply.

Comment: Without pivoting, I don't know that it is better to deal with three columns or one combined; certainly it seems the string-concat and then split seems a bit silly, sure, but it seems to work fine here.

Comment: Does this work well enough?

Comment: Yes, as written it does, except that my dataset actually contains two questions for each theme, named suicide1, suicide2, memory1, memory2, etc, which isn't calculating properly because it's matching to the first one and not the second one. Any thoughts?

Comment: The answers reflect the sample data; if they don't work with the data you provided, then please update your data to better reflect what you have and what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very verbose approach using tidyverse and nnet libraries:

```
library(nnet)
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  select(list, id) %>% 
  separate_rows(list) %>% 
  mutate(list = as.factor(list)) %>% 
  cbind((class.ind(.$list) == 1)*1) %>%  # nnet library
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(list = toString(list)) %>% 
  summarise(across(-c(list, V1), sum)) %>% 
  rename_with(., ~paste(., "score", sep = "_")) %>% 
  rename(id = id_score) %>% 
  right_join(df, by= "id") %>% 
  relocate(list:foil2, everything())
```

```
 A tibble: 6 x 14
  list                       suicide memory alcohol  time foil1 foil2    id alcohol_score children_score memory_score suicide_score time_score vomit_score
  <chr>                        <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>         <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>
1 "suicide memory time"            1      1       0     1     0     0     1             0              0            1             1          1           0
2 "suicide vomit time"             1      0       1     0     0     0     2             0              0            0             1          1           1
3 "vomit alcohol time"             0      0       1     1     0     1     3             1              0            0             0          1           1
4 "  "                             0      0       1     1     0     0     4             0              0            0             0          0           0
5 "  "                             0      0       1     1     0     0     5             0              0            0             0          0           0
6 "alcohol suicide children"       1      0       1     0     0     0     6             1              1            0             1          0           0
```